# Split Set Of Circles into 2 Equal Halves with a Line

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have been trying to answer this question for months now but I am still stuck.

The question requires me to write a program to output YES or NO to whether the given set has a line that can divide it.

I am looking for a possible algorithm to determine the answer, I want to interpret it into code once I have a firm grasp on the answer.

Given an even length set of Circles on a 2D plane that are guaranteed not to touch. determine if it is possible to draw a line through the set dividing it exactly in two without intersecting any circle.

- Circle Radius is greater than zero
- No Circle touches or contains one another
- A set of length 2 is always possible
- every Circle can be unique in size

Input Format:

```
N - number of circles in set
x y r - N lines of: x coordinate, y coordinate, radius
Input repeats until EOF
```

Output YES or NO for each test case

Example input:

```
4
0 0 20
0 40 20
0 30 10
40 -30 10
4
0 0 20
0 40 20
20 40 20
20 -40 20
```

Output:

```
YES
NO
```

---

## Edit: My attempts to solve

**First attempt** was to find all lines that could solve this problem if every circle were zero radius points to give me a set of possible solutions to the problem.

Link to a [Dividing a plane of points into two equal halves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106324/dividing-a-plane-of-points-into-two-equal-halves)

Afterwards I would return the radii back then iterate through each possible solution.

This algorithm was extremely slow (I did'nt bother to calculate the O time since the required algorithm was required to run in a reasonable time frame of a second)

---

My **Second attempt** was to project these circles onto the y and x axis and rotate the set until there existed a section of the x or y axis without a "shadow" of any circle while splitting the sets into two.

This method would only require a maximum rotation of 1/2pi radians to determine the answer but attempts to program were complex and slow.

---

I cannot find the question anywhere online as it was presented on paper last year created by a professor at my university.

Comment: And have you tried anything? O(n^3) algorithm is not hard.

Comment: @Caleb, you can add source of question(like project Euler, spoj etc), if some had solved that, they can help you.

Comment: @Prune - I have updated the question to reflect the absence of my work

Comment: @dkb, This question was written and given by a professor so there are no online records of this question that I could find. I know it has been answered by someone else but I am unable to get their name/contact them.

Comment: @MBo, I have edited the question with a few attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple algorithm with cubic complexity:

Find common tangents for all circle pairs. There are `4*n*(n-1)/2 ~ n^2` tangents.

For every tangent check whether it intersects all circles. `n*n^2=n^3` operations

---

*I think that algorithms with better complexity might exist (based on tangent direction sorting)*

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of this. Ill try it out. Thanks!